# Edge browser fails to load page displaying table built with foreach ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, microsoft-edge

I’m currently facing an issue when I try to run my ASP.NET MVC webapp on Edge browser.

Other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, IE or Opera are working fine but Edge can’t load some pages and displays the following error without any further information:

> Error loading this page
>
> We have tried to load this page several times, but the problem of this site persists and more important tasks must wait for you. So, instead of going on forever, try again later.

**The error occurs when I try to run page where a table is build using @foreach or @for razor synthax** like the following code below:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var maintenanceOperation in Model.MaintenanceOperationViewModels)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => maintenanceOperation.CarMOViewModel.Matriculation)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => maintenanceOperation.CarMOViewModel.CarModel.CarBrand.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => maintenanceOperation.CarMOViewModel.CarModel.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => maintenanceOperation.CarMOViewModel.Mileage)</td>
            <td>@maintenanceOperation.Date.ToString("d")</td>
            @{ 
               var type = EnumHelper<MOType>.GetDisplayValue(maintenanceOperation.Type);
               var status = EnumHelper<MOStatus>.GetDisplayValue(maintenanceOperation.Status);
             }
             <td>@type</td>
             <td>@status</td>
             <td>
                 <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("MaintenanceOperationDetails", "Fleet", new { id = maintenanceOperation.Id })">@Resources.Global_Display</a>
                 <a class="btn btn-success" href="@Url.Action("EditMaintenanceOperation", "Fleet", new { id = maintenanceOperation.Id })">@Resources.Global_Edit</a>
             </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I tried to remove the @foreach loop and now I can access this page (with an empty tbody of course)

Does any of you know something about this issue ? Am I doing something wrong?

My settings:

- .Net Framework v4.6.1
- Razor v3.2.3
- ASP.NET MVC v5.2.3
- Edge v41.16299.15.0
- EdgeHTML v16.16299

Comment: How many rows does the table have? Have you tried doing a .Take(10) or something on the end. It could just be that you're giving Edge more than it can handle.

Comment: @John in this example i'm supposed to have 5 rows

Comment: `"where a table is build using @foreach or @for razor syntax "`...all that processing (using Razor) happens on the server. The browser just receives some static HTML as the output of that processing. Hard to see how the choice of browser could be affected by that (or vice versa). Probably the real issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @ADyson, thank you for your answer. 
As I said in my post, all is working fine on other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, IE, Opera and Safari so I deduced that Edge is the problem here but I might be wrong!
Is there any tips to debug on Edge browser and figure out where the issue come from ?
It might be a thing that Edge's render engine doesn't like but I don't know how to find it.
I will continue my investigation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the issue come from!

There is something that Edge doesn't like from the JQuery plugin that I used with my table.

I fixed it and now everything works properly on Edge.